# Python Tkinter - Close dialog without closing main window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text entry dialog with Tkinter (Python 3.5) but I'm having some problems. This is my code:

```
class TextEntryDialog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.textField = Entry()
        self.textField.pack()

root = Tk()
ted = TextEntryDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this I get a dialog and a main window just like I want, but the problem is that when I close the dialog the main window closes as well. I would like the main window to stay open when the dialog closes, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How are you closing the dialog? If you do `ted.destroy()` it shouldn't close the main window.

Comment: you get something different you think  - `MainWindow` is a window which you think is `TextEntryDialog`. You add `Entry`  to `MainWindow` because you didn't use parent in `Entry`. And you close `MainWindow` but you think you close `TextEntryDialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add titles to windows and you see

[image]

You add `Entry` to `MainWindow`.
And you close `MainWindow` but you think it is `TextEntryDialog`.

You have to add `self.top` (`Toplevel`) as `parent` in `Entry` to put it in correct window.

```
self.textField = Entry(self.top)
```

.

```
from tkinter import *

class TextEntryDialog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.top.title("TextEntryDialog")

        self.textField = Entry(self.top) # parent
        self.textField.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("MainWindow")
ted = TextEntryDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to restructure your code. The following sample application demonstrates how to open a dialog for text entry and prevent closure of the main window when the dialog finishes executing:

```
from tkinter import Label, NoDefaultRoot, Tk
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring


def main():
    NoDefaultRoot()
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Demonstration')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    Label(root, font=Font(root, size=24)).grid()
    root.after_idle(animate_label, root, 3)
    root.mainloop()


def animate_label(root, time_left):
    label = get_any_child(root, Label)
    label['text'] = 'Opening a dialog in {} ...'.format(max(time_left, 0))
    if time_left > 0:
        root.after(1000, animate_label, root, time_left - 1)
    else:
        root.after_idle(open_dialog, root)


def get_any_child(widget, kind):
    return get_any(get_children(widget), kind)


def get_children(widget):
    return iter(widget.children.values())


def get_any(iterable, kind):
    return next(item for item in iterable if isinstance(item, kind))


def open_dialog(root):
    answer = askstring('Text Entry', 'Who are you?', parent=root)
    label = get_any_child(root, Label)
    if answer:
        label['text'] = 'You are {}.'.format(answer)
    else:
        label['text'] = 'I must find out who you are.'
        root.after(3000, open_dialog, root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```